# Why shouldn't I use weird Characters in code/HTML documents?

Tags: html, unicode, ascii

I'm wondering if it's a bad idea to use weird characters in my code. I recently tried using them to create little dots to indicate which slide you're on and to change slides easily:

[image]

There are tons of these types of characters, and it seems like they could be used in place of icons/images in many cases, they are style-able and scale-able, and screen readers would be able to make sense of them.

But, I don't see anyone doing this, and I've got a feeling this is a bad idea, I just can't decide why. I guess it seems too easy to be true. Could someone tell me why this is or isn't okay? Here are some more examples of the characters i'm talking about:

↖ ↗ ↙ ↘ ㊣ ◎ ○ ● ⊕ ⊙ ○　 △ ▲ ☆ ★ ◇ ◆ ■ □ ▽ ▼ § ￥ 〒 ￠ ￡ ※ ♀ ♂ &⁂ ℡ ↂ░ ▣ ▤ ▥ ▦ ▧ ✐✌✍✡✓✔✕✖ ♂ ♀ ♥ ♡ ☜ ☞ ☎ ☏ ⊙ ◎ ☺ ☻ ► ◄ ▧ ▨ ♨ ◐ ◑ ↔ ↕ ♥ ♡ ▪ ▫ ☼ ♦ ▀ ▄ █ ▌ ▐ ░ ▒ ▬ ♦ ◊

PS: I would also welcome general information about these characters, what they're called and stuff (ASCII, Unicode)?

Comment: Strictly speaking, those are not ASCII characters; ASCII only covered `0x00`-`0x7f`.  What is commonly referred to as "ASCII" is [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

Comment: Thanks for the info. So these are considered ISO 8859-1? Thats a mouthful. I never did understand character encoding and whatnot very well. Its always kind of been something that "just worked" for me.

Comment: Actually they're Unicode, but I'm having network difficulties and hit the comment editing limit before I could revise it.

Comment: @AndyGroff the following article should help to understand character encodings http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## There are three things to deal with:

### 1. As characters in a sentence/text:

The problem is that some fonts simply do not have them. However since CSS can control font use you probably will not run into this problem. As long as you use a web safe font, and know that that character is available in that font, you should probably be okay.

You can also use an embedded font, though be sure to fall back on a web safe font that contains the character you need as many browser will not support embedded fonts.

However sometimes certain devices will not have multiple fonts to choose from. If that font does not support your character you will run into problems. However depending on what your site does and the audience you are targeting this may not be a problem for you. Not to mention that devices like that are very old, and uncommon.

All in all it was probably not a good idea a handful of years ago, but now you are not likely to have problems as long as you cover all your bases.

It is important however to point out that you should never hard code those characters, instead use HTML entities. Just inserting those characters into your code can lead to unpredictable results. I recently copied some text from Word directly into my code, Word used smart quotes (quote marks that curve inwards properly). They showed up fine in Notepad++, but when I viewed the page I did not get quotes, I got some weird symbol.

I could have either replaced them with normal quotes `"` or with HTML entities to keep the style `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` (`“` and `”`).

Any Unicode character can be inserted this way (even those without special names).

Wikipedia has a good reference:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

### 2. As UI elements:

While it may be safe to use them in many cases, it is still better to use HTML elements where possible. You could simply style some div elements to be round and filled/not filled for your example.

As far as design goes they are really limiting, finding one that fits with the style of your page can be a hassle, and may mean that you will definitely need to embed a font, which is still only supported by the latest browsers.

Plus many devices do not support heavy font manipulation, and will often display them poorly. It works in the flow of your text, but as a vital part of the UI there can be major problems. Any possible issue one of those characters can bring will be multiplied by the fact that it is part of your UI.

From an artistic stand point they simply limit your abilities too much.

### 3. What are you doing?

Finaly you need to consider this:

- Text is for telling
- Image is for showing
- HTML is for organizing
- CSS is for making things look good while you show them
- JavaScript is for functionality

Those characters are text, they are for telling someone something. So ask the question: "What am I doing?" and then use what was designed for that task. If you are telling use them, if you are showing use Image, or CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. It answered all of my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this done before (the stars) and I think it's an awesome idea! It's also becoming quite popular to use a font (with @font-face) full of icons, like this one: http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/

I can't see any downside to using a font like "font awesome" (only the upsides you mention like scalabilty and the ability to change color with CSS). Perhaps there's a downside to using the special characters you mention but none that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with using those characters is that not all of them are available in all fonts used by all users, which means your application may look strange, or in the worst case be unusable.  That said, it is becoming more common to assume the characters available in certain common fonts (Apple/Microsoft's Arial, Bitstream Vera).  You can't even assume that you can download a font, as some users may capture content for offline reading with a service like Instapaper or Read It Later.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems:

Portability: using anything other than the 7-bit ASCII characters in code can make your code less portable, as recipients may use the wrong encoding. You can do a lot to mitigate this (eg. use UTF16 or at least UTF-8 encoded files). Most languages allow you to specify strings in characters using some form of escape notation (eg. "\u1234" in C#), which will avoid the problem, but loses some of the advantages.

Font-dependency: user interface elements that depend on special characters being available in a font may be harder to internationalize, since those glyphs might not be in the font that you want/need to use for a particular audience.

No color, limited choice of art: while font glyphs might seem useful to a coder, they probably look pretty poor to a UI designer.

Answer (score 1):

The question is very broad; it could be split to literally thousands of questions of the type “why shouldn’t I use character ... in HTML documents?” This seems to be what the question is about—not really about code. And it’s about characters, seen as “weird” or “uncommon” or “special” from some perspective, not about character encodings. (None of the characters mentioned are encoded in ASCII. Some are encoded in ISO-8895-1. All are encoded in Unicode.)

The characters *are* used in HTML documents. There is no general reason against not using them, but loads of specific reasons why some specific characters might not be the best approach in a specific situation.

For example, the “little dots” you mention in your example (probably not dots at all but circles or bullets), when used as control elements as you describe, would mean poor usability and poor accessibility. Making them significantly larger would improve the situation, but this more or less proves that such text characters are not suitable for controls.

Screen readers *could* make sense of special characters if they used a database of various properties of characters. Well, they don’t, and they often fail to read properly even the most common special characters. Just reading the Unicode name of a character can be cryptic or outright misleading. The proper reading would generally depend on meaning and context.

The main issue, however, is that people do not generally recognize characters in the meanings that you would assign to them. How many people know what the circled plus symbol “⊕” stands for? Maybe 1 out of 1,000, optimistically thinking. It might be all right to use in on a page about advanced mathematics or physics, especially if the notation is defined there. But used in general text, it would be just… a weird character, and people would read different meanings into it, or just get puzzled.

So using special characters just because they look cool isn’t a good idea. Even when there is time and place for a special character, there are *technical* issues with them. How many fonts do you expect to contain “⊕”? How many of those fonts do you expect Joe Q. Public to have in his computer? In this specific case, you would find the font coverage reasonably good, but you would still have to analyze it and write a longish list of font names in your CSS code to cover most platforms. In the pile of poo case (♨), it would be unrealistic to expect most people to see anything but a symbol for unrepresentable character. Regarding the methods of finding out such things, check out my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I looked through your guide briefly and bookmarked it for reference. In my interface, I'm using the circles to indicate the users location within a collection and for navigation, but its definitely not the primary control. There are larger links to go left and right, and a text indicator: "2 of 10" It will have arrow key and possibly mousewheel controls when its done. The interface would be usable even if i completely removed the circles. Your points about the question title, fonts, and screenreaders are great! You seem to be an authority on this and i'm glad you answered.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into problems using unusual characters: the tools editor, compiler, interpreter etc.) often complain and report errors. In the end, it wasn't worth the hassle. Darn western hegemony, or homogeneity, or, well, something!